# Yii2 old links not working after pretty urls enabled

Tags: php, .htaccess, yii, yii2

I'm currently updating an existing live website to use pretty urls. I've got the urls working, but my problem is that after I've enabled pretty urls all of the old links from sites like Google etc will stop working. They simply redirect to the front page. Examples;
Old url: http://www.dreambulgarianproperties.com/index.php?r=properties%2Fproperty%2Fview&id=37 Redirects to the front page

New url: http://www.dreambulgarianproperties.com/properties/property/view?id=37 as it should look from both urls.

My .htaccess file is this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule  ^(.*)$ index.php/$1
```

and my UrlManager config is this;

```
'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'enableStrictParsing' => false,
        'rules' => [
            '<action:\w+>' => 'site/<action>'
        ],
    ],
```

The site works fine, I'm just worried about losing Google traffic if I change the urls.

Is there a way of telling Yii to continue parsing old urls, while displaying and handling the new, pretty urls?

Comment: I wouldn't say the new URLs are prettier than the old ones. They do not differ in key word content, and I suppose Google will not care about any changes on this level. However, you need to add permanent redirects from the old URLs to the new ones, otherwise it will be a pretty annoying experience for your users.

Comment: @Sven I'm aware of that, I'll be adding in keyword content later. I'm hoping to avoid having to hard-code redirects for every single page, that would be a right royal PITA.

Comment: You could setup a custom 404 error handler that processes the URI and check if it matches a url in the new structure and if so, does a 301 redirect. Something like: `if (Yii::app()->errorHandler->error->code == 404) `

Comment: @Tristan the problem is that Yii doesn't generate any errors. It simply decides pretty urls are being used, ignores anything after the index.php except the query string, and tries to generate a page based on that. It invariably ends up showing the home page, without logging any errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found away to do this neatly. I extended the UrlManager and updated the parseRequest() method like this;

```
public function parseRequest($request) {
    $url = Yii::$app->request->url;
    if ($pos = strpos($url, 'index.php?r=') == false) {
        return parent::parseRequest($request);
    }
    Yii::trace('Pretty URL not enabled. Using default URL parsing logic.', __METHOD__);
    $route = $request->getQueryParam($this->routeParam, '');
    if (is_array($route)) {
        $route = '';
    }

    return [(string) $route, []];
}
```

Now if there is a query string like index.php?r=controller/action it will process it, otherwise it passes control back to the parent UrlManager for normal processing.

To keep my seo up to date I've added a canonical link in the header of every page so Google knows to use the pretty url for indexing.

Answer (score -1):

inside the **/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/urlManager.php** replace **parseRequest method** to this:

```
    public function parseRequest($request)
{   
    $enable = true;
    $url = Yii::$app->request->url;
    if ($pos = strpos($url, 'index.php?r=') == true) {
           $enable = false;
    }
    if ($enable) {
        /* @var $rule UrlRule */
        foreach ($this->rules as $rule) {
            $result = $rule->parseRequest($this, $request);
            if (YII_DEBUG) {
                Yii::trace([
                    'rule' => method_exists($rule, '__toString') ? $rule->__toString() : get_class($rule),
                    'match' => $result !== false,
                    'parent' => null,
                ], __METHOD__);
            }
            if ($result !== false) {
                return $result;
            }
        }

        if ($this->enableStrictParsing) {
            return false;
        }

        Yii::trace('No matching URL rules. Using default URL parsing logic.', __METHOD__);

        $suffix = (string) $this->suffix;
        $pathInfo = $request->getPathInfo();
        $normalized = false;
        if ($this->normalizer !== false) {
            $pathInfo = $this->normalizer->normalizePathInfo($pathInfo, $suffix, $normalized);
        }
        if ($suffix !== '' && $pathInfo !== '') {
            $n = strlen($this->suffix);
            if (substr_compare($pathInfo, $this->suffix, -$n, $n) === 0) {
                $pathInfo = substr($pathInfo, 0, -$n);
                if ($pathInfo === '') {
                    // suffix alone is not allowed
                    return false;
                }
            } else {
                // suffix doesn't match
                return false;
            }
        }

        if ($normalized) {
            // pathInfo was changed by normalizer - we need also normalize route
            return $this->normalizer->normalizeRoute([$pathInfo, []]);
        }

        return [$pathInfo, []];
    }

    Yii::trace('Pretty URL not enabled. Using default URL parsing logic.', __METHOD__);
    $route = $request->getQueryParam($this->routeParam, '');
    if (is_array($route)) {
        $route = '';
    }

    return [(string) $route, []];
}
```

The method is the same mostly, the difference is inside the first 6 lines.

Comment: @rob006 There is no another way to do old url working, from my point of view